# Problem with building a histogramm and finding 5 biggest values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
white = df.loc[df['winner'] == 'white']

whitestrat = white.groupby(white['opening_name']).agg({'opening_name': 'count'})

display(whitestrat)
```

So, the problem is that i got a dataframe that isn't helpful in building histogram.

```
                           opening_name
opening_name                           
Alekhine Defense                     34
Alekhine Defense #2                   1
Amar Opening                          2
Amazon Attack                         2
Anderssen Opening                     5
...                                 ...
Wade Defense                          1
Ware Defense                          5
Ware Opening                          1
Yusupov-Rubinstein System             8
Zukertort Opening                    64

wwin = whitestrat.opening_name.nlargest(5)

sb.histplot(data = wwin)
```

I tried making a dataframe with 5 biggest values but couldn't plot it correctly

wwin looks like this

```
opening_name
Sicilian Defense     588
French Defense       321
Italian Game         233
Queen's Pawn Game    214
King's Pawn Game     205
Name: opening_name, dtype: int64
```

[image]

How do I make a dataframe with 5 biggest values from whitestrat with their names and make a histogram that contains names as x axis and values as y axis?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the form of your data or whether you want a histogram or bar chart (as you mention values). Taking your final 5 data items as  a DF you could obtain a plot as follows and this could be what you want - else please advise. The approach is discussed in [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart/)[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Opening Name': ["Sicilian Defense", "French Defense", "Italian Game", "Queen's Pawn Game", "King's Pawn Game"],
                  'Value' : [588, 321, 233, 214, 205]
                   })

print(df)

x = df['Opening Name']
y = df['Value']

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))

def addlabels(x,y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.text(i, y[i], y[i], ha = 'center')

plt.bar(x, y)
addlabels(x, y)

plt.show()
```

prints

```
        Opening Name  Value
0   Sicilian Defense    588
1     French Defense    321
2       Italian Game    233
3  Queen's Pawn Game    214
4   King's Pawn Game    205
```